# How to run a home server on a Ubuntu laptop over WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, ubuntu-18.04

I wish to use my old Dell Inspiron laptop as a Ubuntu server. I want to then access this server via a local IP address, and the server will respond to SSH, HTTP etc. using its WiFi card. That is, I don't want to connect my machine (Windows 10 laptop) to my Ubuntu server via an ethernet cable, or any other wire. I also want my Ubuntu server to share the internet connection that I have on my Windows 10 laptop. I currently use my mobile phone's data plan and tether the Android phone to my windows 10 laptop for internet access.

Could you provide a general outline of the steps I should take to make this happen, please? The steps should ideally be such that I can use google to get the more detailed, concrete steps.

***Edit***: I am not looking for details of how to set up the services on the Linux server, as I am familiar with running apache, etc. I only want information on how to do the networking aspect. I just want to be able to access this server over WiFi from within my home and for it to share the internet connection on my Windows laptop. I don't want to reach it from outside my home network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you provide a general outline of the steps I should take to make this happen, please?

To use your old laptop as a server:

1. Install Ubuntu on your laptop.
2. Install and configure any necessary server software:

   - For HTTP, you will want a [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server). Apache is a popular choice and has a large number of tutorials on how to configure it.
   - For SSH, you may want to consider OpenSSH Server.
   - For other kinds of access (e.g. FTP), you may need to do additional research into servers that support the kind of access you would like to have.
3. Open any appropriate ports in the laptop firewall. For HTTP, you should have at least port 80 (HTTP) open to incoming requests. SSH uses port 22 by default. Other options (e.g. HTTPS, which is port 443, etc.) will require other ports to be open.

**Firewall Notes**

- While the available (unblocked) incoming ports on your firewall are likely the most important for your server to function properly, you may need to configure the server's available outgoing ports as well (depending on circumstance).
- Other computers or devices on your network (i.e. those attempting to communicate with your server) may need their firewall settings adjusted, too.
- Your router shouldn't need adjustment unless you plan to make your server available outside your local network (i.e. accessible from the Internet). If this is the case, you will need to set up [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router (which may or may not include manual firewall adjustments).

> I want to access this server via a local IP address using its WiFi card.

After taking the general steps above, you will need to connect the server to your local network via its WiFi card (as you would normally) and note its assigned local IP address.

Assuming you've set everything up correctly (including any server/client software and appropriate firewall settings for all your communicating devices), you can then use this IP address to access your server (e.g. enter it into a browser address bar, give it as the destination IP for SSH, etc.).

> I also want my Ubuntu server to share the Internet connection that I have on my Windows 10 laptop. I currently use my mobile phone's data plan and tether the Android phone to my Windows 10 laptop for Internet access.

If you are using your phone as a WiFi hotspot, simply connect your server to that hotspot. If you are using USB tethering, you will need to configure your Windows laptop to share its Internet access via its WiFi card (i.e. act as a hotspot, rather than the phone).

If you want to access your server from any device outside your network, however, you may run into trouble. In this case, your phone is acting as your modem/router and it may or may not allow proper access to certain ports while connected to your data plan (your carrier may block these ports or there may be other technical limitations).

Finally, as a side note, connecting a server via WiFi is likely extremely insecure. WiFi presents a large number of possible ways for an attacker to gain access to your network. Other security considerations aside, it would be much better to run your web server from a wired connection (even if it isn't preferable).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Will I be able to assign a static IP address to my Ubuntu server if I connect it to my WiFi hotspot (for use within my home network, of course, not outside it)?

Comment: @ARV, please edit your question. if this gets closed because of your lack of action, The person who took the time to answer you (Articulated well I might add) will not get any credit for it. Regards,

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have made the question as specific as I could. Please see the edit. It's unfortunate that the mods are trigger happy with closing questions.

Comment: @ARV To your initial comment regarding using a static IP, given that hotspots are usually made for sharing the Internet with random devices, I would lean towards it being unlikely (but I couldn't say for 100% certain, unfortunately). That said, if nothing else, it is definitely possible to set up a hosted network with a static IP on Windows and use a simple DHCP server such as [DHCP Server for Windows](http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/) to serve up the same address to a client based on its MAC.